# Using the for-loop effectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my webpage, I have to animate a different number of images per tab. In one tab, I have to animate three images. In another, I have twenty images to animate.

Presently, I am using two for-loops to handle this. I know it's a silly way of handling it; is there a better way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
function nextimageelev() {
    var elevcounter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (elevcounter == i) {
            $("#" + i).fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + i).hide();
        }
    }
    if (elevcounter < 2) {
        elevcounter++;
    }
    else {
        elevcounter = 0;
    }
}
```

How do I make it more flexible to avoid hard-coding the conditional part? Currently, I have to write two for-loops to handle two animations.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply add a common class to the elements you want to animate so you can use that as your selector:

```
$('.someClass').fadeIn();
```

Comment: sry i forgot to add, the condition is like ,when i click on the link it will fade in and will continue to do so(automatic kind of thing) ,untill i exit.
will then the answer work as well

Comment: @Sham I am not quite sure what you mean. I do know however that if you have a set of common elements that you want to apply the same actions to, you are better of referencing them with a common selector via a class (or via some other common property like positions in DOM).

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the OP's requirement that some elements `.fadeIn()` and some `.hide()` or offer a way to manage their counter.  That's the more interesting part of this problem and what enables a simpler version of the code or not.

Comment: @ Mike Brant i will definitely give a try on your solution.

by the way my requirement is when the user clicks upon the link ,all the images present (3 here) will fade in one after another after a particular time period (let say after 1 sec)  and will continue to do so ,until the user exits.